# How to access env variables outside of modules in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I have a project that has a helper folder filled with helper functions or axios instances and i need to access my env files there.

`ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: envFiles, isGlobal: true})`

This works inside all modules but i cant use process.env in non module files.

Answer (score 1):

just install dotenv 'npm install dotenv --save' to your dependencies and then add to your non module files code bellow, this will load your data from env.

documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();
const data = process.env.SOME_DATE;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.